# Symfony API, form submissions vs json api

Tags: json, symfony-forms, symfony, fosrestbundle

Quick question regarding submitting both form data and json data to a Symonfy endpoint.

I have FosRest bundle and a form with a `PercentType`

The `PercentType` transforms .95 to 95 for the view purposes, which means when submitting via a form 95 is expected. However my API sends and receives data in the model format ie 0.95.

Now when a user POST's json to the api 0.95 is transformed by the form to 0.0095 (dividing by 100).

I want to use the form in both cases to map, transform and validate data.

My first guess was to change the `PercentType` to `NumberType` depending on the request format (json vs html). Alternatively disable the transformer.

Has anyone got any experience with this situation? It's the same issue for MoneyType when storing values as cents.

Comment: Have you tried adding your own `ModelTransformer`? If you need I can paste some codes on how to achieve that.

Comment: The PercentType and MoneyType have their own transformers. As I said in the question I think I might have to try and disable the transformer depending on the request format.

Comment: You can still stack your transformer *after* the built-in transformers.